# I am not able to figure out a bug that is when I try to click on a link on my website it appears the 404

Tags: php, web, hosting, web-hosting

My website is coded in PHP and hosted in Hostinger. The problem is that when I want to go to another link, for example the contact section or the about section it appears the 404 Not Found Page. However, I have tried the same files on local server and it works fine. Would the problem be with the code or with the host provider.

link of my website: http://tranvio.com

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /public_html
RewriteRule ^details-(.*)?$ index.php?a=details&id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^recovery-(.*)?$ index.php?a=recovery&hash=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^refid=(.*)?$ index.php?refid=$1 [L]
```

Comment: have you used .htaccess file in your project ? if yes then show us your code for redirect link.

Comment: permission related issue.

Comment: I have created the .htaccess and added few stuff, I am gonna update the question and add the code of the .htaccess

Comment: It is because of unspecified `RewriteBase /` base

Comment: @FahadKazmi So what should I specify there?

Comment: Try removing it.

Comment: you can asssign RewriteBase value to your home page domain link also. example : 'RewriteBase /tranvio'

Comment: @GaurangSondagar by replacing RewriteBase / with RewriteBase /tranvio still get the same error

Comment: @FahadKazmi By removing it gets the same error.

Comment: show us code of your htaccess file for redirect link

Comment: Please share your url rewrite rules specified in your `.htaccess` file

Comment: @FahadKazmi this is all the code that I've put on the .htaccess file

Comment: @GaurangSondagar this is all the code that I've put on the .htaccess file

Comment: Then why you are not using file `extension` in the links as instead of `/page/about` there should be `page/about.ext` where `ext` is file extension that your pages have.

Comment: Also can you share your directory listing here?

Comment: @FahadKazmi in that case the extension is PHP, however, if I type manually tranvio.com/page/about.php will still give me the 404 not found page

Comment: @FahadKazmi you mean the structure of the directory listing?

Comment: Yes. the structure of files in directories

Comment: @FahadKazmi http://imgur.com/a/uVQiY

Comment: I am not able to see here neither `testimonial` folder or file nor `pages` folder which you are specifying in url as `pages/about` or `/testimonial` etc... please upload the files and give the correct path in `link` with file extensions

Comment: yeah, @FahadKazmi , you are right . upload those folders in root directory.

Comment: @FahadKazmi http://imgur.com/a/8uEBa, now if i try the section testimonials.php I still get the same error

Comment: @GaurangSondagar imgur.com/a/8uEBa, now if i try the section testimonials.php I still get the same error

Comment: `http://tranvio.com/testimonials.php` this url is working to me

Comment: @FahadKazmi What is the text that comes?

Comment: Please post another question for other problems the question about the problem with your url I think it's solved.

Comment: @FahadKazmi is not solved since if you try and click the links it would redirect you to the 404 not found page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question solved:

Edit the .htaccess to this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(login|register|forgot-
password|testimonials|logout|submit-testimonial)?$ index.php?a=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^page/(contact|about|faq|privacy-policy|terms-of-service)?$ 
index.php?a=page&b=$1 [L] RewriteRule ^account/(exchanges|wallet|wallet_exchange|deposit|referrals|settings|with
drawals|withdrawal)?$ index.php?a=account&b=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^account/exchanges/(.*)?$ index.php?
a=account&b=exchanges&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^account/exchange/(.*)?$ index.php?
a=account&b=exchange&id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^account/referrals/(.*)?$ index.php?
a=account&b=referrals&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^ref/(.*)?$ index.php?refid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^password-recovery/(.*)?$ index.php?a=password-
recovery&hash=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^become_payment/(.*)?$ index.php?a=become_payment&id=$1 [L]`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^testimonials?$ TESTIMONIAL_FILE_PATH_HERE [L]
```

put your .htaccess file in your root directory folder if it's not there.

Comment: This is what I put                                                                       
      `RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /tranvio
      RewriteRule ^/?$ tranvio / [L]
      RewriteRule ^testimonials?$ sources/testimonials.php [L]`

Comment: write your home page file full path addressing your php file as you comment in your second rule. same in your first rule also.

Comment: Ok, putting into that way `RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /http://tranvio.com/index.php
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://tranvio.com/index.php/ [L]
RewriteRule ^testimonials?$ sources/testimonials.php [L]`                            it works but now if you go to the testimonials section it says **Bad Request**

Comment: try to remove RewriteBase and firstrule also. hope it work.

Comment: New error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function checkSession() in /home/u140593186/public_html/sources/testimonials.php on line 9
`

Comment: that means your testimonials.php file has checkSession() function error. check that file , and see checkSession function is define or not in your file.

Comment: Yea, it is defined it is coded in that way `if(checkSession()) {...}`

Comment: checkSession() function is not defined in your testimonials.php page, you have just used that function without including/defining in your file, if i'm correct.

Comment: If that is the case then why the same files work on local server (XAMPP)?

Comment: try to run that file on your localhost and show us a screenshot of that page.